# How to display a dashboard on visualforce page and refresh it automatically at 2 pm and 8pm regularly

Tags: visualforce, dashboard

How to display a dashboard on visualforce page and refresh it automatically at 2 pm and 8pm regularly.

i am using the following code:

```
<apex:page sidebar="false"> 
       <apex:iframe src="https://cs10.salesforce.com/01ZJ00000000N2n?isdtp=nv" 
                    scrolling="true" 
                    height="1588px" width="100%"/> 
</apex:page>
```

Even though dashboard is not displayed.. please provide help

Comment: Is the dashboard a visualforce chart or is it a "standard" dashboard?

Comment: standard Dashboard

Comment: i have used analytic controller chart tag ... and i have given salesforce report Id ... it is displaying the dashboard .... can i get this refreshed

Answer (score 2):

See the following help page: [Schedule a Dashboard Refresh](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=dashboards_schedule_refresh.htm). You can only schedule a dashboard refresh once per day. You can't guarantee that it will occur at the exact time you specify, but it will happen within the 30 minutes from the start time you set it for. You can set it refresh daily, weekly or monthly at a specific start time, day or date of the month (as applicable). You can also set the the start and end dates for the refreshes. You can have up to 200 dashboard refreshes/month in an EE edition.

I've not tried it, but you might attempt to schedule daily refreshes at different times of the day. That's the only way I can see making this happen. The interface won't allow you to set multiple refreshes for the same dashboard all at once.

One possible work around might be to refresh the source reports on the schedule you desire for the alternate time. Again, something I've not tried, but worth seeing if it might work for you since dashboards are based on the report. This would be a good solution for a visualforce chart which is why I asked what type of dashboard charts you have. Unfortunately, like dashboards, reports can only be scheduled for refresh once/day.

Comment: I need a visualforce page where i have to display the dashboard and then it should refresh at 7 pm and 2 Am

Comment: I got that loud and clear from your original message. Read the docs I pointed you to and also see if some of the suggestions might work to get it to refresh more than once/day. More than once/day isn't standard functionality in an EE org.